# How uninstall TeXLive 2013 under Windows 8?

Tags: installing, texlive

How does one uninstall the previous version (2013) of TeXLive under Windows (Windows 8, to be specific).

Comment: And, I presume, edit PATH to delete the texlive\2013 entry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Uninstall it like you would any other program](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/uninstall-change-program).

[Search for "Uninstall a program"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/search-apps-files-settings) (part of the Control Panel), find and select *TeX Live 2013* and click *Uninstall/Change*:

[image]

This should work for any version of TeX Live.

Comment: Doesn't work for Tex Live 2015 on Windows 10

Comment: @Clive: Why doesn't this work? It worked for my TeX Live 2016 and I can see TeX Live 2017...

Comment: After I click "Uninstall/change", a black command prompt window pops up and quickly disappears. Nothing happens afterwards.

Comment: @Clive: Perhaps there was something that went wrong with your initial installation.

Comment: I don't even get that entry with TeXLive2017 ... and I checked all the potential registry locations for the uninstall key and indeed there is none. That's problematic because some tools such as TeXStudio rely on that information.